# Schoeps Microphone Trivia

Tags: schoeps, trivia, microphone, gear

Hey guys,

This isn't exactly a question but I thought it was cool information to know about Schoeps mics:

I was at NAB this year and I saw the new [SuperCMIT](http://digital.schoeps.de/en/products/supercmit) shotgun (digital shotgun which is super-directional with different noise cancelling settings)

Anyway, the Schoeps staff member there said it was specifically made for the World Cup games so the TV broadcasters could hear the ball being kicked. That's the only reason they made it in the first place. They ordered 50 of them. Then, they decided to release it on the market.

The soccer sound guys were trying to figure out how to get a mic near the ball or around it and even inside the ball (which was my suggestion) but as we know the ball is sacred and must not be messed with. So they asked Schoeps to design a mic that was super-directional and so now we have the SuperCMIT.

I just thought that was kind of cool trivia.

[Schoeps SuperCMIT http://digital.schoeps.de/IMG/products/product_pics/SuperCMIT.png](http://digital.schoeps.de/en/products/supercmit)

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for that. The World Cup is on my side of the world, I should try find out more about these babies! 

Comment: I have just started on a shoot where I will be swinging one of them babies about...just from the gear check today I must say I am extremely impressed with the directionality of this mic!

Answer (score 6):

I art directed a shoot where we used a [Schoeps CMIT](https://web.archive.org/web/20161015141434/http://www.schoeps.de:80/en/products/cmit5u) (not the super) for all the dialog, inside. It bucked the "don't use a shotgun inside" advice and it sounded **AMAZING**. Can't imagine how the SuperCMIT would sound in real-world production.

[Schoeps CMIT http://www.schoeps.de/IMG/products/product_pics/cmit5u.gif](https://web.archive.org/web/20161015141434/http://www.schoeps.de:80/en/products/cmit5u)

I'm kinda surprised that the obvious answer - use a parabolic mic, like a [Telinga](http://www.telinga.com/) - wasn't the way the World Cup people went. Anyone have a technical reason why that wouldn't be a good idea?

[image: Telinga parabolic microphone]
<sub>(source: [telinga.com](http://www.telinga.com/gallery/bild2.JPG))</sub>

Comment: +1 that it sounded amazing. I put that regular "blue" shotgun up against an MK41 and it blew it out of the water inside. You have to place it below the person - though. Above him pointing down (which is where I wanted to put it) sounded bad to me. As far as the parabolic mic, dunno. Maybe you get too much other stuff? Like the crowd?

Comment: I seem to remember hearing that this particular Schoeps shotgun mic has a different sort of pickup pattern that makes it less prone to the sort of off-axis response patterns that plague most other shotgun mics indoors or near reflective surfaces.

Comment: That is the argument that Schoeps make.  They were anti-shotgun mics for so many years.

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to find the specs on the physical connection of the [Schoeps SuperCMIT](http://digital.schoeps.de/en/products/supercmit).  As I understand from the website it's 2 standard XLR connectors with a processed signal one one cable, untouched signal on the other.

It's interesting seeing the electronics that go into new microphones.  Reminds me of the [Neumann TLM 103 D](https://www.neumann.com/?lang=en&id=current_microphones&cid=tlm103d_description) - fully digital, no need for preamps, A/D conversion, etc.  It would be very cool to see digital field mics as well.  Instead of XLR cables, we'll be running fiber, or using something wireless.

[image: Neumann TLM 103 D]

Comment: The SuperCMIT is a hybrid analog/digital mic. The two XLR connectors are for the two formats of signal. One is your typical analog output, while the other is AES 42 for digital signal. If you want to use the digital output though, you'll obviously need an AES 42 interface (same as the 103D). Digital Phantom Power is not the same as regular Phantom Power.

Answer (score 1):

I got a chance to play with the CMIT and it is truly amazing. I recorded some dialogue for fun from different angles and distances in different locations and the reverse noise cancellation is something to behold. Also, they have an incredible reach- up to 4-5 metres away and you can still get decent dialogue. The pads and roll offs are also excellent. I would definitely buy one if I had the money. Thanks Scheops.

Answer (score 1):

... just don't connect the super-cmit to a battery-powered box.. 170mA!